# Should clicking cancel midway through a wizard just cancel the changes on this page or the whole wizard?

Tags: wizard

Hope someone can help this is driving me crazy.

I have a wizard for creating a new user on the system.

Step 1: Basic information
Step 2: User access rights
Step 3: Files etc

At step 1 I have a "Next" button which takes you to step 2.

If the user gets to step 2 and clicks "Cancel", should it save what was inputted at step 1 but not save anything that has been done at step 2? This would then create some kind of draft user than needs to complete setup at a later time.

Or should clicking cancel at step 2 not even create a draft record and instead lose everything inputted at stage 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you don't have anything that says just **Cancel**, which is ambiguous, as you've discovered.

If there's a button that saves a draft for later, name it **Save a Draft**. To cancel the entire process, use a button that says that explicitly: **Cancel New User**.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a right or wrong answer, but there are different strategies to help to manage user expectations.

I suspect that if the process is long and there are many inputs required for the user then they will want to be able to save and come back to it. So you need to provide them with this action/option somewhere.

Conversely, for a short series of steps in which not much input is required and that it is a one-off event, there is no particular need to be able to come back to it.

So your ideal design lies somewhere between the two extremes and you should design the content and actions appropriately.

Users are not really going to remember what they did at each step, so a conservative approach would be to save the whole process rather than just the one step. But again it depends on the length and type of information that you are asking for, because they might not want to save private or sensitive information.

And in case a user accidentally clicks on the cancel button, you should probably ask for a confirmation and whether they want to save the information.